# Accessing Dts.Connections from a new class

Tags: c#, ssis

I am using a Script Task in SSIS.  In my ScriptMain.cs, I have the following code:

```
namespace Program
{
    [System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
    public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public void Main()
        {
            int connectionCount = GetConnectionCount();
            NewClass n = new NewClass();
            connectionCount = n.GetConnectionCount2();
        }

        public int GetConnectionCount()
        {
            return Dts.Connections.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

And in my NewClass:

```
namespace Program
{
    public class NewClass : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
    {
        public int GetConnectionCount2()
        {
            return Dts.Connections.Count;
        }
    }
}
```

When my GetConnectionCount() method executes, I am able to bring back the count for the number of connections in SSIS's Connection Manager.  When I try running GetConnectionCount2() however, no matter what references I add/try, I always get a System.NullReferenceException error.

How can I access Dts.Connections from a new class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always pass Dts.Connections as an argument for the constructor of your NewClass.

**Edit:**
I tried to reproduce your code in the most similar way. It could be done this way, accordingly to that:

```
[System.AddIn.AddIn("ScriptMain", Version = "1.0", Publisher = "", Description = "")]
public partial class ScriptMain : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{ 
    #region VSTA generated code
    enum ScriptResults
    {
        Success = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Success,
        Failure = Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Runtime.DTSExecResult.Failure
    };
    #endregion

    /*
         Info regarding Script Task usage.
    */

    public void Main()
    {
        int connectionCount = GetConnectionCount();
        DTSReadOnlyCollectionBase arCon = Dts.Connections;
        NewClass n = new NewClass(arCon);
        connectionCount = n.GetConnectionCount2();
        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }

    public int GetConnectionCount()
    {
        return Dts.Connections.Count;
    }
}

public class NewClass : Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Tasks.ScriptTask.VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
{
    DTSReadOnlyCollectionBase dtsConnections;

    public NewClass(DTSReadOnlyCollectionBase dtsCon)
    {
        dtsConnections = dtsCon;
    }

    public int GetConnectionCount2()
    {
        return dtsConnections.Count;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: Can you provide an example?  I can then mark yours as an answer.